# Why yield return does not work when modifying local data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension and currently adding margin glyphs to the editor. I have started with the walk-through example from MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-creating-a-margin-glyph?view=vs-2017.

My logic is a bit different from the example since I don't analyze the file content given by the spans parameter: I already get a set of results with defects locations from an analysis process before. And the rationale is simply to generate a tag if and only if it has not been rendered yet.

Indeed, I want to avoid a new glyph is falsely be rendered if the user adds a new line the line before an existing flag. Example: if there is a glyph on line 42, and cursor is on line 41, and user types a new line, then a new glyph is generated on line 42 (because the GetTags method is called again) while previous glyph is moved to line 43.

My code is:

```
internal class MyDefectTagger : ITagger<MyDefectTag>
{
    private IClassifier m_classifier;
    private ITextBuffer m_buffer;

    internal MyDefectTagger(IClassifier classifier, ITextBuffer buffer)
    {
        m_classifier = classifier;
        m_buffer = buffer;
    }

    IEnumerable<ITagSpan<MyDefectTag>>
        ITagger<MyDefectTag>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        var filename = GetFileName(m_buffer);

        if (MyModel.Instance == null || 
            MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation == null || 
            !MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation.ContainsKey(filename))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (SnapshotSpan span in spans)
        {
            ITextSnapshot textSnapshot = span.Snapshot;

            foreach (ITextSnapshotLine textSnapshotLine in textSnapshot.Lines)
            {
                var line = textSnapshotLine.LineNumber + 1; // Lines start at 1 in VS Editor

                if (MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation[filename].ContainsKey(line) &&
                    !MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation[filename][line].rendered)
                {
                    MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation[filename][line].rendered = true; // YIELD WORKS IF THIS LINE IS COMMENTED OUT
                    yield return new TagSpan<MyDefectTag>(new SnapshotSpan(textSnapshotLine.Start, 0), new MyDefectTag());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

        public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged;

        private string GetFileName(ITextBuffer buffer)
        {
            buffer.Properties.TryGetProperty(typeof(ITextDocument), out ITextDocument document);

            return document?.FilePath;
        }
    }
```

What is strange is that yield returns normally when the "rendered = true" line is commented out (although I get false new glyphs). While yields seems to be blocked when line rendered = true is run (while debugger still steps on the yield instruction).

Is there anything I am missing? Is it forbidden to modify local data when using yield return? Is there some hidden concurrency issue? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you mean to `yield break` instead of `yield return null`. You test `MyModel.Instance` for `null` but the next time `MoveNext` is called on the iterator, `if (!MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation...` is reached and that could cause a NRE.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I fixed that and retried. I still get the problem. Unless the "rendered = true" instruction is commented out, yield return seems to return nothing while the debugger still steps on it... Any idea?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "seems to return nothing" - overall I'm pretty confused by what your code is trying to do, and what you're observing. If you could simplify it into a [mcve] that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Let me explain. When I say "seems to return nothing", I mean that I don't get a single glyph rendered when executing "rendered = true", while I still can see the debugger stepping on the yield return instruction. As for the code simplification, this is already quite minimal: as I said in the introduction, I don't need to analyze the spans since the analysis is already done before. I am getting a list of defects grouped by file and by line (in defectsLocation). I just want to display a margin glyph for each line containing a defect (without getting false new glyphs when adding new lines).

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?

Comment: @Lance: I cannot easily provide a smaller example that I can copy and paste here. I propose I provide a zip on a "working" and minimal example reproducing the problem as I did on another thread. I'll be back in a while.

Comment: @Lance: I think we'll need more support / training from MS. How to communicate directly and avoid spamming here?

Comment: @Stephane Hi friend, please check [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=ca91a7d4-f9cb-fb09-1979-911a7c0d3a89), you can get something like 1:1 support there and hope it helps:(

Comment: @Lance: Don't mistake it. I am very fine with your help! It is just me who requires more intensive help as I have a lot of other topics I haven't posted here yet and we don't have experts here internally. Since it looks like you are from MS, it would be just great if you could be the person providing this official support / training. I am checking what support contract we have here. Maybe you can track my support request on your side when I have posted it. And I am still interested in your suggestions on the other threads ;-) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Lance: Sorry I cannot make a reduced example in a zip as I have other problems to solve before :-( Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651201/how-to-get-line-number-on-iclassifier-getclassificationspans but with ITagger<T>.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans: how to current current span line number :-( ?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea for this. And what the update of the 1:1 support? Wish it can help:)

Comment: Hi! Sorry no update yet about the 1:1 support. First needs to browse the companies wires before I get the right person. I will get back to you as soon as I have news :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that I was not correctly scanning lines given by the NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans. I was wrongly re-iterating through all the lines for each span with `foreach (ITextSnapshotLine textSnapshotLine in textSnapshot.Lines)`. In fact I needed to get the line number associated with the given span and now it works:

- I get margin glyphs appropriately on each line my analysis give me a defect.
- I don't get any more duplicates when adding new lines just before a line having a margin glyph.

Hence my solution is:

```
        foreach (SnapshotSpan span in spans)
        {
            var lineNumber= span.Snapshot.GetLineNumberFromPosition(span.Start.Position) + 1;

            if (MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation[filename].ContainsKey(lineNumber) &&
                !MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation[filename][lineNumber].rendered)
            {
                //MyModel.Instance.defectsLocation[filename][lineNumber].rendered = true;//Strangely no getting any MyDefectTag displayed when I uncomment this line...
                yield return new TagSpan<MyDefectTag>(new SnapshotSpan(span.Start, 0), new MyDefectTag());
            }
        }
```